# Convert hours to correct division by 60 minutes

Tags: javascript

How would I convert a number such as the following: **12.82** into the correct hourly format: **13.22**?

Comment: Is number format are always like 12.82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
timeold = "12.84";
time = timeold.match(/(\d+)(\.\d+)?/);
if (time[2] >= .60) {
    time[2] = time[2] - .60;
    time[1] = parseInt(time[1]) + 1;
 }

 alert(time[1] + time[2]);
```

Comment: Did you seriously just copy my answer?

Comment: @michael :Check your answer with an input of `12.121`.

Comment: You're right, doesn't work. Will be interesting if it is of concern for OP as only numbers from 0.01 to 0.99 might count. Of course the if will be false with .121 as .121 is smaller than .60 ...

Comment: @Ullas, please check it with numbers that really affect the time, as 12.784, or 12.984 -- anything that will be more than 60 minutes.

Comment: @michael: OP might be used the `.` for just separating the hour and    minute

Comment: Well, I don't think so and the question doesn't really sound like that, but we'll never know until he tells. But I'm quite positive that there won't be 3 decimals and, we can't doubt that, .60 is a higher number than .12334323. There's quite little information on that, let's just wait what he thinks.

Comment: By the way, if we are talking about posibilities... Try the .split method without any decimals like 12 - this will break it all... I think it'll be really hard to find a solution that fits every need

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulus operator. ie

```
var time = "12.82".split(".");
var minutes = time[1]%60;
var hours = parseInt(time[0]) + Math.floor(time[1]/60);
var newTime = hours + "."+ minutes;
```

Comment: You have convert the `hours` to integer.

Comment: just have seen that you've fixed it, deleted the second option from mine

Answer (score 0):

```
var t="12.82";

min=t.split('.');
hour=Math.round(min[1]/60);
actualHour=parseInt(hour)+parseInt(min[0]);
actualMin=min[1]%60;

formattedTime=actualHour+':'+actualMin;
```

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txtDt"/><br /><br/>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="dt()" />
```

### JS

```
var dt = document.getElementById('txtDt').value;
        var d=dt.split(".");
        var hr=d[0];
        var min = d[1];
        if (min > 60) {
            var q = Math.floor(min / 60);
            hr = parseInt(hr);
            hr += q;
            var newmin = min - (60 * q);
            alert(hr + '.' + newmin);
        }
        else {
            alert(dt);
        }
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/9329/)